# Copy to clipboard href url in row table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, row

I have php file where I get data from db and I created table for that. There is id, title with url and next to it is button and I'm trying to copy href url by click the button, but it copies only first row url.

Example if I click row 3 copy button, it copies always url1.com.

HTML PART:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <a href="http://url1.com" id="copythis">Url 1</a>
              <button class="copybutton"></button>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <a href="http://url2.com" id="copythis">Url 2</a>
              <button class="copybutton"></button>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <a href="http://url3.com" id="copythis">Url 3</a>
              <button class="copybutton"></button>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

JS PART:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<script>

 var link = document.getElementById("copythis");
 var href = link && link.href;
 new Clipboard('.copybutton', {

 text: function() {
   return href;
  }
 });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the same id on the three `anchor` elements. They should all have their own id.

Here is the library doc: https://clipboardjs.com/

Here is a working solution, with pure javascript and clipboardjs.
The solution uses the `trigger` passed to the `text` function to fetch the `href` attribute on the previous sibling `trigger.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('href')`:

```js
new Clipboard('.copybutton', {
  text: function(trigger) {
    return trigger.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('href');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="http://url1.com" id="copythis1">Url 1</a>
        <button class="copybutton">Button 1</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="http://url2.com" id="copythis2">Url 2</a>
        <button class="copybutton">Button 2</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="http://url3.com" id="copythis3">Url 3</a>
        <button class="copybutton">Button 3</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" placeholder="Paste here">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to comment, but this copy only e.g. Url 1. Not the href url.

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer to fetch the href attribute on the element. It should now work